# flask_sqlalchemy : .commit() not updating object in production environnement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am building a website with flask and python.
I finished developing it, but now that I am trying to deploy it changes to the database are not done consistently.

For example, when I try to update an object it doesn't change in the database every time. The same code does exactly what it should while running in development environment, the issue only happens when the website is in production.

You can take a look at small example of code that reproduce the way I try to update objects :

```
import flask_sqlalchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
@views.route('random-route')
def random_route() :
    object = ObjectClass.query.filter_by(id='some_id').first()
    object.some_property = 'some diffrent value'
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('some_template.html')
```

This is a reproduction of the code i am actually running in my app. Also the object does exists as well as the property. Also the route that is supposed to do the modification is reachable through a GET request.

Do you have any idea why this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to solve this issue.
You need to merge your changed object in the session before committing.

```
object.some_property = 'some diffrent value'
db.session.merge(object)
db.session.commit()
```

Not sure why this is needed only in production tho

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary - it suggests that you might have a misconfiguration somewhere, for example `db` is defined in more than one module.